# Proving and identity with the normalized sine function

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

I have no idea where to begin with proving the following

$$ \prod\limits_{i=1}^\infty \cos\left(\dfrac{t}{2^i}\right) = \dfrac{\sin( t)}{t}$$
I couldn't do it by expanding the cosine and no trigonometric identities appeared helpful.

Maybe someone has encountered that before? Hints welcome!